# Find polygon centroid with Shapely given vertices with lat, lon

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

Trying to find the centroid of Polygon with Shapely but I do not understand how to tell the library that the vertices are (lon, lat). Perhaps I need to set a projection?

Here is my code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

# LON, LAT
vertices = [
    Point(-79.8726944444444, 8.68505555555556),
    Point(-79.8733888888889, 8.50419444444444),
    Point(-79.54552777777779, 8.68386111111111),
    Point(-79.54622222222221, 8.503),
    Point(-79.8726944444444, 8.68505555555556),
]

p1 = Polygon(vertices)
centroid = p1.centroid
print(centroid)

# POINT (-1805804163717.8823 6592764402.930745)
```

The result is clearly wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is, but the units shouldn't matter in the slightest.  If you remove `Point` and just pass a series of 2-tuples, do you get the right answer?

Comment: @TimRoberts no I get the wrong answer still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a degenerate shape. It's bowtie that crosses itself. Shapely can't handle that.

Shapely does allow a polygon to narrow itself to zero width at one spot.  If you reorganize the data by including the center point, it works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

# LON, LAT
vertices = [
    (-79.8726944444444, 8.68505555555556),
    (-79.8733888888889, 8.50419444444444),
    (-79.7091111111111, 8.594625),
    (-79.54622222222221, 8.503),
    (-79.54552777777779, 8.68386111111111),
    (-79.7091111111111, 8.594625),
    (-79.8726944444444, 8.68505555555556)
]

p1 = Polygon(vertices)
print(p1)
print(p1.area)
print(p1.bounds)
print(p1.centroid)

plt.plot( [v[0] for v in vertices], [v[1] for v in vertices] )
plt.show()
```

Comment: oh wow - is there a way to handle it - resolve it somehow?

Comment: I think I can use a MultiPoint